# C# FileSystemWatcher and it's selected directory's own changes

Tags: c#, .net, filesystemwatcher

So I have a filesystemwatcher that notifies me of changes all under the selected folder but I noticed that if I delete or rename the folder that is being watches, it is not detected. How would you detect if the watched folder is renamed or deleted?

Comment: Watch its parent. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.renamed(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_1

Comment: some code pls..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"notifies me of changes all **under** the selected folder"

Watch the folder above. Maybe even have 2 watchers.

Comment: Gotcha. Thanks a lot.